# How can I add attributes to craft field?

Tags: field, custom-fieldtype

In my template I have this,

```
{{ 
    craft.fields
    .getFieldByHandle('ethnicOrigin')
    .getFieldType()
    .getInputHtml( 'fields[ethnicOrigin]', '') | raw
}}
```

which returns me a `<select>` html element Is it possible to add specific class to this select and or `data-` attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the [FieldType](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/field-types) documentation it looks as the you need to create a template for the input field in which you can specify the actual html for your field. The example in the documentation is for a `textarea` but in your case you can substitute this for a `select`.

Then once you've done that just override the `getInputHtml` method to render your new template.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I would like to get my custom field `ethnicOrigin` which options are comming from the database.

Comment: I've updated the answer, that should be more useful to you.